# Breakbox box placed on a new page instead of breaking the page

Tags: page-breaking, boxes

I made a list of serveral items that I'd like to be framed. That was no problem with `\fbox{...}`. Since the text is not longer than 1 page, it goes straight to the next page insteat of starting in the middle of the page where it belongs. I tried with `\breakbox{}` but it still goes to the next page. How can I change it my code so that it makes the page break where it should ?

```
\begin{breakbox}%{\linewidth}    
\begin{itemize}    
    \begin{multicols}{3}    
    {\small     \myitem a    
        \myitem b    
        \myitem c    
        \myitem n    
        ...     
    \end{multicols}    
\end{itemize}    
\end{breakbox}
```

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please help us help you and add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. Reproducing the problem and finding out what the issue is will be much easier when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[image]

`itemize` will not break inside a `multicol` environment within a frame. An alternative would be the `tasks` package, in which you can specify the number of columns as you wish the same as `multicol` but it allows page break at the right position. `mdframed` is also very rich boxing environment, which I recommend here. See the [`mdframed` documentation](http://ctan.asis.io/macros/latex/contrib/mdframed/mdframed.pdf) for more information on how the `mdframed` environment can be used. Here is a MWE:

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{multicol,tasks,mdframed,lipsum}

\DeclareInstance{tasks}{myitemize}{default}{%
enumerate = false,
label-width = 1.125em,
label-offset = 0.6em,
label-format = \bfseries
}
\settasks{style= myitemize}%

\begin{document}    
\lipsum[1-4]    
\begin{mdframed}[linecolor=red,backgroundcolor=yellow!40]
\small
\begin{tasks}(3)       
     \task a    
     \task Item b    
     \task Item c    
     \task Item n 
     \task a    
     \task Item b    
     \task Item c    
     \task Item n 
     \task a    
     \task Item b    
     \task Item c    
     \task Item n   
\end{tasks}  
\end{mdframed}    
\end{document}
```

Comment: Why do you say "`itemize` will not break inside a `multicol` environment."? Of course it breaks: `\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[a6paper]{geometry}
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}    

\lipsum[1]
\begin{multicols}{3}    
\begin{itemize}    
  \item a    
  \item b    
  \item c    
  \item n    
  \item a    
  \item b    
  \item c    
  \item n    
  \item a    
  \item b    
  \item c    
  \item n    
  \item a    
  \item b    
  \item c    
  \item n    
\end{itemize}    
\end{multicols}    

\end{document}` Am I misunderstanding you?

Comment: @GonzaloMedina  This is what we are interested in: `\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{multicol,mdframed,lipsum}
\begin{document}    
\lipsum[1-3]    
\begin{mdframed}[linecolor=red,backgroundcolor=yellow]
\small
\begin{multicols}{3}
\begin{itemize} 
\item a 
\item b 
\item c 
\item n 
\item a 
\item b 
\item c 
\item n 
\item a 
\item b 
\item c 
\item n 
\item a 
\item b 
\item c 
\item n 
\item a 
\item b 
\item c
\end{itemize} 
\end{multicols}
\end{mdframed}    
\end{document}`

Comment: Ah, the "within a frame" that you added in your edit clarifies everything. My comments will vanish shortly. +1, by the way.

Comment: Thank you @AboAmmar, that works very good. But now the label is this dot and I'd like no label at all, just the words. If I just put [] behind \begin{tasks}[]{3}, it doesn't change a thing. How can I change this ? Then it would be perfect.

Comment: @BiancaMertens Three possible answers: 1) In each task use `\task[] ...` 2) Use a `label={{}}` in your Instanse declared. 3) Use the command `\renewcommand{\labelitemi}{}`, but be careful not to change the normal behavior of `itemize` globally. I recommend number 2) for you.